# Dual Operating System using cloning software

Tags: cloning

If I clone my windows 7 ultimate of a 410 think pad and back it up to a new HP Laptop with windows 10 and using dual Operating systems will it work?

Comment: **Very** unlikely that this could work. You'd need different drivers for different motherboards. A Harley carb is unlikely to work in a Triumph.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple Windows system? Most likely not.  One Windows system and one or more Linux systems? No problem...

First, to get dual boot going you'll need some boot loader that can handle multiple windows versions.  I know the old WinNT4/Win2k had `boot.ini` and that is how we set up dual boot on machines for Linux/Windows using `lilo` 20 years ago.  `GRUB` may be a possibility also.

Assuming your dual boot loader is solved (and I'd start at `boot.ini` and then go to `GRUB`) then the issue will be drive letters, various registry entries, and even hard-coded to `C:` paths in various applications.  This is manageable when there is only one primary partition that is FAT*/NTFS but with multiples then whatever is on the second one is going to have issues.  It can be made to work, but there may be much hair pulling and gnashing of teeth.  Doing a fresh install of the second OS so that it does get `D:` (or whatever) drive letters in the path will make it much easier - but updating this on a cloned system is a painful process.

Then once you get it all working and you have that sense of accomplishment, it kinda goes away in a hurry. To be totally honest dual booting is a pain - you are never running the OS you "need" to be at the moment.  With the resources available on current hardware (and even not-so-current hardware) I'd consider just throwing some more RAM in the system, pick one of the two versions of Windows as "primary" and run the other via VirtualBox, VMWare, or other virtualization technologies.

Answer (score -1):

If your Windows 7 box is OEM (many are) you cannot move it to another platform. Virtualization (as noted above) is much more flexible.

I have a Windows 7 Pro machine here on my Windows 10 Po laptop using VMware Workstation. Works great.

Hyper-V works as well.